Construct two isomorphic valuation rings over $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ which are not equal as subsets of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$
I constructed the following (standard) valuation on $\mathbb{Q}(x)$: Let $f$ be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Write $\mathfrak{f} \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ as $\mathfrak{f} = f^{a}\mathfrak{g}$ for $\mathfrak{g} \in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Define the valuation $v_{f} : \mathbb{Q}(x)^{*} \to \mathbb{Z}$ as $v(\mathfrak{f}) = a$. It can be checked that this defines a valuation on $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. Similarly define the valuation $v_{f^{'}}$ for an irreducible $f^{'}$. Now I checked that the associated valuation rings of $v_{f}$ and $v_{f^{'}}$ are non-isomorphic. How to get two isomorphic valuation rings which are not equal as subsets of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$

What's the relation of $f$ and $f'$?               (I guessed they are not have to be same.)         Anyhow, I think you have to make clearly what's the question or proposition that you asking...

$f$ and $f^{'}$ are both irreducibles and they are different. So they give rise to distinct valuations.

We can produce such examples by using automorphisms of $\Bbb Q(x)$. Take for example the automorphism $\varphi$ determined by $x \mapsto x+1$. This automorphism restricts to an isomorphism between the valuation rings $\Bbb Q[x]_{(x)}$ and $\Bbb Q[x]_{(x+1)}$ which are not equal as subsets of $\Bbb Q(x)$.

Perhaps such isomorphisms exist only between valuation rings defined by distinct irreducible polynomials of degree one ? (Each obtained by restrictions of the corresponding automorphisms of $\mathbf{Q}(x)$) ?

The degree one polynomials would of course have to be monic and defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ for the automorphisms and their restrictions to be defined.

If the valuation rings are isomorphic, then necessarily the unit groups in these rings should also be isomorphic. But this is not true for any pair in the set $\{v_f, v_{f'}, v_\infty \}$ (where $v_f$, $v_{f'}$ are the standard valuations corresponding to distinct irreducible polynomials $f,f'$ and
$v_\infty$ is the degree valuation corresponding to the element $1/x$).
So necessarily, if we assume that the valuations are trivial on $\mathbf{Q}$, the possibility of constructing such valuation rings does not exist (since any non-trivial valuation $v$ on $\mathbf{Q}(x)$ (that is trivial on $\mathbf{Q}$) is determined by setting either $v(x) \geq 0$ or $v(x) < 0$, and the valuations $v_f$
(corresponding to irreducible polynomials $f$) and the degree valuation
$v_\infty$ exhaust all such possible choices).
Edit: Above holds for non-archimedean valuations.

Can we have a valuation on $\mathbf{Q}(x)$ that restricts to the $p$-adic valuation on $\mathbf{Q}$ ?  And how can we describe it ?

I don't agree with the argument and also not with the conclusion. There are lots of valuations $v$ on $\Bbb Q(x)$ which are trivial on $\Bbb Q$ such that $v(x)=0$. Take for example, the $x-q$-adic valuation for any $q \in \Bbb Q$ with $q\neq 0$. All these valuations have isomorphic valuation rings.

@LukasHeger  There was a typo in my answer post (which I have corrected now) -- it should have been "... either $v(x) \geq 0$ or $v(x) < 0$ ..."   Also the $f$-adic valuations which you are referring to do not have isomorphic valuation rings, since for $q_1 \neq q_2$ (elements of $\mathbf{Q}$) and the corresponding valuations $v_{f_1}, v_{f_2}$, the element $x-q_1$ is a non-unit w.r.t. $v_{f_1}$ but is a unit w.r.t. $v_{f_2}$.

@LukasHeger  In fact $v_x$ and the degree valuation $v_\infty$ are the only non-trivial valuations $v$ on $\mathbf{Q}(x)$ for which $v(x) \neq 0$. All other valuations have $v(x) = 0$. Thanks for pointing out.

The automorphism of $\Bbb Q(x)$ sending $x$ to $x+1$ does map units in $\Bbb Q[x]{(x)}$ to units in $\Bbb Q[x]{(x+1)}$, so I don't know what you mean.

@LukasHeger. Yes, I agree. Your example shows I made a mistake.
